# Silent Install for Files

Tags: batch-file, group-policy

I'm trying to create a script to install some files, sequentially.  However, I want them to be installed with no user interaction.

Here's what I got so far:

```
cd "C:\Users\Tom\Documents\ScreenConnect\Files"
IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files (x86)\Citrix\ICA Client\SelfServicePlugin\SelfService.exe" (
 C:\Users\Tom\Documents\ScreenConnect\Files\CitrixReceiver-4.4.1000.exe
)

IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\Cloudwerx\CloudwerxPlugin\uninstall.exe" (
 C:\Users\Tom\Documents\ScreenConnect\Files\cloudwerx-setup.exe
)
```

I want to install silently so the user doesn't see the install.  I've tried , /s, /S, /silent, and /Silent.

Comment: @RGuggisberg can you make an answer... I definitely tried /silent already.  I feel like an idiot... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to see if any HELP is shown: C:\Users\Tom\Documents\ScreenConnect\Files\CitrixReceiver-4.4.1000.exe /?